# MySQL wrong count value when left join

Tags: mysql, join

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

This Works and produces desired results
(Get a list of recipes and the total amount of rating in the ratings table)

```
SELECT recipes.RecipeID, 
       recipes.Name, 
       recipes.RatingTotal, 
       recipes.ImageBig, 
       users.Email, 
       users.FullName, 
       users.UserImageBig, 
       COUNT(ratings.RecipeID) AS trates 
FROM   recipes 
       LEFT JOIN users 
              ON recipes.User = users.Email 
       LEFT JOIN ratings 
              ON ratings.RecipeID = recipes.RecipeID 
GROUP  BY RecipeID 
ORDER  BY RecipeID DESC 
LIMIT  3
```

This Does not work
(Get a list of recipes and the total amount of rating in the ratings table and the total number of comments as well. the query runs but the values are wrong in the count columns)

```
SELECT recipes.RecipeID, 
       recipes.Name, 
       recipes.RatingTotal, 
       recipes.ImageBig, 
       users.Email, 
       users.FullName, 
       users.UserImageBig, 
       COUNT(ratings.RecipeID)        AS trates, 
       COUNT(recipecomments.RecipeID) AS crate 
FROM   recipes 
       LEFT JOIN users 
              ON recipes.User = users.Email 
       LEFT JOIN ratings 
              ON ratings.RecipeID = recipes.RecipeID 
       LEFT JOIN recipecomments 
              ON recipecomments.RecipeID = recipes.RecipeID 
GROUP  BY RecipeID 
ORDER  BY RecipeID DESC 
LIMIT  3
```

If there are 2 comments, it returns 4 double of the actual number. Also ratings will become 4.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the schema for the recipes, users, ratings, and recipecomments tables? Also, please run the following query: SELECT Email, count(*) FROM users GROUP BY Email HAVING count(*) > 1.

Answer (score 2):

In second query you have added another left join with `recipecomments` which surely have a many to one relation so there will be repeated rows for `RecipeID` and the count will morethan your expected result so for your problem you need to use `distinct` in your count function to count only the unique instances,Also for `crate` count the ids of `recipecomments`

```
SELECT recipes.RecipeID, 
       recipes.Name, 
       recipes.RatingTotal, 
       recipes.ImageBig, 
       users.Email, 
       users.FullName, 
       users.UserImageBig, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT ratings.RecipeID)        AS trates, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT recipecomments.ID) AS crate 
FROM   recipes 
       LEFT JOIN users 
              ON recipes.User = users.Email 
       LEFT JOIN ratings 
              ON ratings.RecipeID = recipes.RecipeID 
       LEFT JOIN recipecomments 
              ON recipecomments.RecipeID = recipes.RecipeID 
GROUP  BY RecipeID 
ORDER  BY RecipeID DESC 
LIMIT  3
```

Comment: Whoops , no something not right , crate , trate and frate never return a value greater than 1

Comment: @ZaidKajee consider providing sample data set @[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) also for `trates` count  `ratings`'s id and  what is `frate` ? you have not describe this one your question please update your post